# BLE: Executing the bluez test "test-proximity"

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, dbus, bluez

Hey i got some trouble running the ./test-proximity. I'm using bluez-5.16 and dbus-1.8.0.

In the folder test/ is the BLE text for PXP profile.

To call it i wrote: ./test-proximity -i 0 -b 88:33:14:E5:EE:A1 LinkLossAlertLevel mild

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test-proximity", line 52, in <module>
    device = bluezutils.find_device(options.address, options.dev_id)
  File "/home/pi/bluez-5.16/test/bluezutils.py", line 29, in find_device
    return find_device_in_objects(get_managed_objects(), device_address,
  File "/home/pi/bluez-5.16/test/bluezutils.py", line 9, in get_managed_objects
    manager = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object("org.bluez", "/"),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 241, in get_object
    follow_name_owner_changes=follow_name_owner_changes)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 248, in __init__
    self._named_service = conn.activate_name_owner(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 180, in activate_name_owner
    self.start_service_by_name(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 278, in start_service_by_name
    'su', (bus_name, flags)))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.bluez was not provided by any .service files
```

It seems like there is something wrong with .service files. But i can'f find them.

thanks in advance

Comment: is bluetoothd running in ur device

Comment: Yes, i tested it with nexus 4 , asus Bt400 and hm-10

Comment: [This page](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=172491) suggests: Try to comment out the bluetooth modules in /etc/pulse/default.pa

Comment: it will not solve, as the link suggest that the person was not using bluez hence pulseaudio package was giving that error, @RobAnderson : You mean you tested bluez5 with nexus4 ?

Comment: Bluez is running on a linux machine. But i expect to see the services when i use the nexus4 with a BLE App. It indicates that the problem is the bluez configuration.